# Pandas: How to accumulate returns - forecasting prices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, return, finance

I have a pandas dataframe of stock prices indexed by date (monthly data). I want to compute the following: starting with 100 stocks at Jan 31, 1983 worth $4100 (41.00 per stock) what is the maximum absolute value of stocks in march 2012, if I could have accurately forecasted next month's ending price.

- if next months end price higher than this months end price: buy stocks for full amount of cash and fully participate at stock returns
- if next months end price lower than this months end price: sell all stocks and take the cash at beginning of the month (do not participate in stock losses)

[image]

Here is some sample data to work with:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['1983-01-01','1983-02-28','1983-03-31','1983-04-30','1983-05-31'],
    'Month End Price': [41.00,46.75,44.25,50.00,59.25]
}).set_index('Date')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

For example in Feb 1983 stock price increased from 41.00 to 46.75, which is a return of 14.02% that month. So my stocks, initially worth 4100$, would rise to 4100$*(1+14.02%)= $4675 for end of Feb 1983.

In Mar 83, there is a negative return (as price declines from 46.75 to 44.25). Having had known that decline, I would have sold all stocks worth $4675 end of Feb (not participating losses) and then reinvest in the beginning of April 1983.

In April 1983, stocks performance is +12.99% (50.00/44.25 -1), so my net worth would increase from $4675 to $4675*(1+12.99%) = $5282.5 until end of April 1983.

Comment: Can you please show some sample output and be little specific on what you need

Comment: for example in Feb 83 stock price increased from 41.00 to 46.75, which is a return of 14.02% that month. So my stocks, initially worth 4100$, would rise to 4100$*(1+14.02%)= $4675 for end of Feb 1983. In Mar 83, there is a negative return (as price declines from 46.75 to 44.25). Having had known that decline, I would have sold all stocks worth $4675 end of Feb (not participating losses) and then reinvest in the beginning of April 1983. In April 1983, stocks performance is +12.99% (50.00/44.25 -1), so my net worth would increase from $4675 to $4675*(1+12.99%) = $5282.5 until end of April 1983.

Comment: Please post some minimal reproducible code of what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I did it with Excel: created a new column "Monthly Return" as: (Month end Price[t] - Month end Price [t-1]/ Month end Price [t-1]. and a second new column with an "if" statement: if (return[t]>0;Money[t-1] * (1+ return[t]); Money[t-1]) - any ideas how to implement with Python?

Comment: Your monthly return column would be: `df['Month End Price'].diff() / df['Month End Price']`. For the next column, I'm not sure what "Money" column you're referring to.

Comment: ah sorry, I have a fixed starting investment of 100 stocks worth 41$ each - so there is no 'Money column' in the beginning, but I am interested how this columns evolves

Comment: @DominikScheld see the response. This is a relatively compact way to do it, if I get your intent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this more compactly, but I will set up with a few intermediate columns so the logic is clear. First, I'm going to set up a sample dataset with a few ups and downs.

```py
import pandas as pd

prices = [50.00,46.75,44.25,50.00,59.25,66.50,
          29.25,44.25,59.25,61.00,64.25,65.25]
dates = pd.date_range('01-31-1983','12-31-1983', freq='m')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Month End Price':prices}, index=dates)
```

This yields a dataframe that looks like this:

```
           Month End Price
1983-01-31            50.00
1983-02-28            46.75
1983-03-31            44.25
1983-04-30            50.00
1983-05-31            59.25
1983-06-30            66.50
1983-07-31            29.25
1983-08-31            44.25
1983-09-30            59.25
1983-10-31            61.00
1983-11-30            64.25
1983-12-31            65.25
```

And this:
[image]

You can compute the month-to-month price fluctuations as:

```py
df['Monthly Returns'] = df['Month End Price'].diff()/df['Month End Price']
```

We want to realize all gains and avoid all losses, from what I understand. I set up a multiplier column that equals 1 for months when we should have avoided losses and is basically `1 + df['Monthly Returns']` for months with gains. Then I compute a `Cash` column as the cumulative product of the `Multiplier` column times $41, which was our principal. There is a temptation to use a `for` loop here, but with Pandas, anytime you see a `for`, there's often a quicker, built-in like `cumprod`:

```py
df['Multiplier'] = df['Monthly Returns'].apply(lambda x: max(x, 0)) + 1
df['Cash'] = df['Multiplier'].cumprod() * 41
```

Once all that is done, we have something that looks like:

```
           Month End Price  Monthly Returns  Multiplier        Cash
1983-01-31            50.00              NaN         NaN   41.000000
1983-02-28            46.75        -0.069519    1.000000   41.000000
1983-03-31            44.25        -0.056497    1.000000   41.000000
1983-04-30            50.00         0.115000    1.115000   45.715000
1983-05-31            59.25         0.156118    1.156118   52.851941
1983-06-30            66.50         0.109023    1.109023   58.613995
1983-07-31            29.25        -1.273504    1.000000   58.613995
1983-08-31            44.25         0.338983    1.338983   78.483145
1983-09-30            59.25         0.253165    1.253165   98.352296
1983-10-31            61.00         0.028689    1.028689  101.173878
1983-11-30            64.25         0.050584    1.050584  106.291623
1983-12-31            65.25         0.015326    1.015326  107.920614
```

And the value of the positions look like this:

[image]

Comment: thansk a lot, mayosten, for your great answer! just one more addition: until now, you simulate the cash development not taking into account that whenever next months' return is negative, I have to sell all my stocks (starting with 100), and need to buy stocks when next months return is positive again - as stocks can only be purchased in integers (whole numbers), there might be a difference in here, correct? Do you have an idea how to incorporate the buying/selling of integer number of shares for respective month end prices (i.e. by accounting for remaining cash in a separate column?)

Comment: @DominikScheld I think you are correct here, the answer I've provided is very generic and doesn't take this into account, nor does it take transaction costs into account. You would need to expand on this to get there. For example, you need a column to track cash on hand, a column to track how many shares of each stock are owned at any given time, and some logic to calculate the number of shares purchased using integer division. E.g. `n_shares = cash_available // share_price`.